# Is there a naming convention for javascript variables that hold functions?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

```
setup: function (baseUrl, devModeCheck) {
```

where `devModeCheck` is a function that will be called.

Is there any commonly-used naming convention in javascript that makes this intention obvious?

`devModeCheckFunc` and `fDevModeCheck` both seem kind-of horrible.

Comment: if its a call back function then I generally use "cback". but most of all documentation will assist you in understanding your code at a later date or another developer having to read it.  Always document

Answer (score 2):

`callback` is a pretty common naming convention. For simpler higher order functions it holds well, but if you write more complicated code it may not be that simple (like if you have several callbacks).

As with naming anything in code, make the intent clear on what something is. `callback` may be too generic in some instances, or it may be too specific in others.